# Spark: How to get String value while generating output file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two files

```
--------Student.csv---------
       StudentId,City 
       101,NDLS 
       102,Mumbai

 -------StudentDetails.csv---
       StudentId,StudentName,Course 
       101,ABC,C001 
       102,XYZ,C002
```

**Requirement**

1. StudentId in first should be replaced with StudentName and Course in the second file.
2. Once replaced I need to generate a new CSV with complete details like

   ```
   ABC,C001,NDLS
   XYZ,C002,Mumbai
   ```

**Code used**

```
 val studentRDD = sc.textFile(file path);
 val studentdetailsRDD = sc.textFile(file path);
 val studentB = sc.broadcast(studentdetailsRDD.collect)

 //Generating CSV
 studentRDD.map{student =>
     val name = getName(student.StudentId)
     val course = getCourse(student.StudentId)
     Array(name, course, student.City)
 }.mapPartitions{data =>
     val stringWriter = new StringWriter();
     val csvWriter =new CSVWriter(stringWriter);
     csvWriter.writeAll(data.toList) 
     Iterator(stringWriter.toString())
 }.saveAsTextFile(outputPath)



 //Functions defined to get details
 def getName(studentId : String) {
     studentB.value.map{stud =>if(studentId == stud.StudentId) stud.StudentName}
 }

 def getCourse(studentId : String) {
     studentB.value.map{stud =>if(studentId == stud.StudentId) stud.Course}
 }
```

**Problem**

File gets generated but the values are object representations instead of String value.

How can I get the string values instead of objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in another answer, Spark's DataFrame API is especially suitable for this, as it easily supports joining two DataFrames, and writing CSV files.

However, if you insist on staying with RDD API, looks like the main issue with your code is the lookup functions: `getName` and `getCourse` basically do nothing, because their return type is `Unit`; Using an `if` without an `else` means that for some inputs there's no return value, which makes the entire function return `Unit`.

To fix this, it's easier to get rid of them and simplify the lookup by broadcasting a `Map`:

```
// better to broadcast a Map instead of an Array, would make lookups more efficient
val studentB = sc.broadcast(studentdetailsRDD.keyBy(_.StudentId).collectAsMap())

// convert to RDD[String] with the wanted formatting
val resultStrings = studentRDD.map { student =>
  val details = studentB.value(student.StudentId)
  Array(details.StudentName, details.Course, student.City)
}
  .map(_.mkString(",")) // naive CSV writing with no escaping etc., you can also use CSVWriter like you did

// save as text file
resultStrings.saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark has great support for `join` and `write` to file. `Join` only takes 1 line of code and `write` also only takes 1.

Hand write those code can be error proven, hard to read and most likely super slow.

```
val df1 = Seq((101,"NDLS"), 
              (102,"Mumbai")
          ).toDF("id", "city")
val df2 = Seq((101,"ABC","C001"), 
              (102,"XYZ","C002")
          ).toDF("id", "name", "course")

val dfResult = df1.join(df2, "id").select("id", "city", "name")

dfResult.repartition(1).write.csv("hello.csv")
```

There will be a directory created. There is only 1 file in the directory which is the finally result.

Comment: Thanks Rockie. I tried this approach and it was really very simple and straight forward.

Comment: I just have one question. How can I process those column for which I need to implement some logics before displaying it ? Does dataframe has similar features as SQL ?

Comment: Spark DataFrame has a lot of built-in functions to process columns, and provide the ability to extended with UDF (User Defined Functions). The programming guide shall be a good start https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html